# What is probability of 2 independents events occurring given that another event has already occurred?

Tags: conditional-probability

On Wikipedia on page relative to [Conditional probability](https:////https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) in section Statistical independence it is written following

*It should also be noted that given the independent event pair [A B] and an event C, the pair is defined to be conditionally independent if the product holds true:[17]*

$$P(AB\mid C)=P(A{\mid}C).P(B{\mid}C)$$

Is that equivalent to say that

If A and B are two mutually **independent** events, than

$$P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A{\mid}C).P(B{\mid}C)$$

Is that true ?

How can I prove the last formula ? Wikipedia is citing her source, but cited book are not readable  online !

PS: I have "corrected" Wikipedia sentence today. Perhaps that my correction is incorrect !

Comment: Yes. $P(AB|C)$ is another way to write $P(A\cap B|C)$. It can also be written $P(A,B|C)$.

Answer (score 0):

Last formula is not true in general. For example taking
$$\Omega =\{ 1,2,3,4 \}, A = \{1, 2\}, B=\{ 2,4 \}, C=\{1,2,4\},$$ with classical probability give you pair of independent events $A, B$. But
$$P(A\cap B| C) = \frac 1 3$$
and
$$ P(A| C)P(B| C) = \frac 2 3 \cdot \frac 2 3 = \frac 4 9.$$

This shows that your definition of conditionally independent events actually introduces something **different to regular independence**. It could be thought of as independence in restricted space $C$.

Comment: I'm not sure that your answer is correct because in your example A and B are NOT independant. You (or me) confuse event intersection with set intersection ! For me A∩B is the probability that A occurs in omega set and than B occurs in omega set. For you, A∩B is the probability that intersection of A and B sets occurs in omega set. This is not the same thing. I'm not sure that my syntax (A∩B) is correct for event !

Comment: Intersection of sets (events) is exactly the event of "both events happening". I think your confusion might come from not understanding definition of probability space properly. Also, as I read your question again, my answer could have been off-topic. But comment of John Douma wasn't.